# UCK Fails on 17.04, Won't create Image

Tags: 17.04, uck

So when I run UCK on 17.04 with english, spanish, and french as the languages and GNOME and "others" selected as the DEs, I get this error:

> > Installing language packs (en es fr)... Reading package lists... Building dependency tree... Reading state information... language-pack-en is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-en-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-es is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-es-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-fr is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-fr-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-en is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-en-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-es is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-es-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-fr is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). language-pack-gnome-fr-base is already the newest version (1:17.04+20170404). Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: language-pack-touch-en : Conflicts: language-pack-en but 1:17.04+20170404 is to be installed language-pack-touch-es : Conflicts: language-pack-es but 1:17.04+20170404 is to be installed language-pack-touch-fr : Conflicts: language-pack-fr but 1:17.04+20170404 is to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base language-pack-touch-en language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-es language-pack-es-base language-pack-touch-es language-pack-gnome-es language-pack-gnome-es-base language-pack-fr language-pack-fr-base language-pack-touch-fr language-pack-gnome-fr language-pack-gnome-fr-base failed, error=100 Restoring kernel update state... Reactivating initctl... mv: cannot stat '/sbin/initctl.uck_blocked': No such file or directory Reactivating update-grub... Reactivating grub-probe... Reactivating grub-probe postinst/postrm... Removing generated machine uuid... Removing generated fstab/mtab... Removing crash reports... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/var/cache/apt... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/tmp/customization-scripts... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/tmp... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/sys... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/run... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/root... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/proc... Unmounting /home/jack/tmp/remaster-root/dev/pts... Cleaning up temporary directories... Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.

I am extremely sorry about this being so long, this is an excerpt from the build.log file.
Does anyone know how to fix this? Or at least find an alternative to building
distros on and based on Ubuntu 17.04?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UCK unfortunately, is discontinued! Although there are several alternatives to UCK. I personally find that SUSE studio also does not work. There are several alternatives that can be found [here](http://alternativeto.net/software/uck/) but I would recommend [this](http://alternativeto.net/software/linux-respin/) which is LinuxRespin which is not limited to Ubuntu. Hope it Helped.